# Do not display fields

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Do not display "host" and "port" fields. Please help find the error.

```
<!--ContentPanel – поместите здесь дополнительное содержимое-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,14,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ConnectionName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TitleServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Host, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,130,10,436" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Host" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="345"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Port" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="100" InputScope="Number"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Login, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,314,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Password, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,340,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you want to hide those two textblocks or those two textblocks are not showing in the screen?

Comment: Two TextBox are not showing in the screen.

Comment: ok. Just check with my answer & let me know if the problem still there.

Comment: Why do you use a `Grid`? You use it to stack controls vertically using margins. I think you'd better replace the `Grid` by a vertically oriented `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,14,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ConnectionName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TitleServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Host, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,130,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Host" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="345"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Port" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="100" InputScope="Number"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Login, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,314,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Password, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,340,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
    </Grid>
```

The issue was with StackPanel's **Margin** Property. Please note that i added **VerticalAlignment** Property too.

> Actually you simply need to use StackPanel as ContentPanel instead of
>   using Grid , so that you can place your controls one below one order
>   without giving any Margin.And that will be more easier

Comment: Your answer will probably be the correct one, but it was pretty unclear to me what he meant. I thought he wanted to hide them...

Comment: Thx all! The answer helped. Sorry for bad English, translated by Google translator.

Comment: @Abbas yes , just i thought the same , but i had a doubt that's why i asked him for more details.

Comment: @AndreyG. Actually you simply need to use StackPanel as ContentPanel instead of using Grid , so that you can place your controls one below one order without giving any Margin.And that will be more easier.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will do as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [**visibility-property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the StackPanel to `Collapsed` or `Hidden`. Or, set this property on each of the TextBox controls separately if you prefer.

```
<StackPanel Visibility="Collpased" Margin="0,130,10,436" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Host" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="345"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Port" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="72" Width="100" InputScope="Number"/>
</StackPanel>
```

More info on the property from MSDN:

- *Visible*: Display the element.
- *Hidden*: Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.
- *Collapsed*: Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.

Comment: These actions have not helped